# How to make appear collection in the email?

Tags: meteor

I’m making an app, where users can leave their comments. All reviews are going to Mongo collection. Every week cron-job takes records from collection and sent them by e-mail.
I used the code below and I got not what was expecting. Email text was just: [Object, object].
Can anyone can explain me how should I properly write this line:

```
var myMessages = FeedbacksList.find({}).toString();
```

to get my app work corectly?

**ALL CODE:**

```
// Methods
Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
        Email.send({
            to: to,
            from: from,
            subject: subject,
            html: text
        });
    }
});
Meteor.methods({
    'feedbacks.insert'(emoji, feed, timeSet) {
                FeedbacksList.insert({
                    feedback: emoji,
                knowFrom: feed,
                createdAt: timeSet
                });
    }
});

var myMessages = FeedbacksList.find({}).toString();

// Cron Job for weekly email sending
SyncedCron.add({
    name: 'Jura Ataskaitos',
    schedule: function(parser) {
        // parser is a later.parse object
        return parser.text('at 9:00 am on Mon');
    },
    job: function() {
        const sendM = Meteor.call('sendEmail', 'karolis.arbaciauskas@gmail.com', 'karolis@pretendentas.lt', 'test', myMessages);
        return sendM;
    }
});

// Start Cron
SyncedCron.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following returns a *cursor*

```
FeedbacksList.find({})
```

If you want to get all the records returns by this, then you need to fetch them:

```
var messages = FeedbacksList.find({}).fetch()
```

Or you can iterate over them:

```
FeedbacksList.find({}).fetch().foreach(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: if I'm using `var messages = FeedbacksList.find({}).fetch().toString();` I still can't parse real data just: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`  Any ideas?

Comment: by the way everything is on the server side